# ie8 and firefox posting incorrectly (works in other browsers)

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, http-post

I am doing an ajax POST request with jQuery, and this works except I get blank parameters from Firefox 4 and ie8.

I'm not sure how to debug this and can't find this issue being a problem for anybody else, can anyone suggest the cause?

I don't think this is related to the "cross-domain" issue as it happens on several servers (clones) and there is no alternative domain used in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was caused by a second DOM object with the same id, just in case anyone has a similiar problem :).

I was renaming ids in javascript, once it tried to change the id to an existing one, it failed, which screwed up later processing.